# upload file is not working

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am using the simplest method to upload an image file, but I'm getting an error.

**My code:**

```
<?php 
    $targetfolder = "uploads/";
    $targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " is uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "Problem uploading file";
    }
?>
```

What am I doing wrong in my code?

**The error:**

> Notice: Undefined index:upload\upload.php on line 3
>   Notice: Undefined index:upload\upload.php on line 4

HTML FORM

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000000" />
 Send this file: <input name="file" type="file" />
 <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
 </form>
```

Comment: You must be using a form to choose and send the filename? Where's your form

Comment: Can you show us the result of `var_dump($_FILES);` placed just after the `<?php`?

Comment: form coding is also added

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, the file haven,t been uploaded to your server side. Please cheak your post_max_size in your php.ini file. If this value is small than you uploading file, will cause the error you explained, remember that, **post_max_size** should at least be a little bigger than you uploading file.
Another parameter you need to config is the **upload_max_size** in the php.ini, too.

php.ini is somewhere like

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: i checked php.ini file, 'Post_max_size = 3M' and 'upload_max_filesize = 64M'

Comment: you uploading filesize is?

Comment: uploading filesize is max 300KB

Comment: attach your hole html code